# ¿Como es posible verificar si un array ingresada por teclado esta ordenada en python?

Tags: python, array

Aquí mi duda, tengo el objetivo de realizar un programa que pueda verificar si los elementos ingresados por teclado en un array, se encuentran ordenados:

```
n=3
 for i in range(n):
    x=int(input("Valores: "))
    array.append(x)
```

No es ordenar una lista, es verificar que la lista está o no está ordenada,intenté y no encontré el camino adecuado para resolver el problema.

Comment: Publica lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes los datos ingresados? Hace falta ver la implementación, ya que dependiendo de la misma harás una u otra verificación. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Ordenada como? Tal vez te sirva `if sort(lista) == lista: #Código`. A tu pregunta le faltan muchos detalles, si deseas verificar si está en un orden en especifico, debes de implementar una lambda en la compración (del `sort()`) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La estrategia usual cuando te enfrentes a un cálculo díficil (¿está ordenada la lista?) es pensar en una función que lo solucione.

En este caso construimos una función que recibe una lista y retorna un valor booleano `True` o `False`, según la lista cumpla o no la condición de estar ordenada (cada elemento mayor o igual al elemento anterior).

El proceso es simple: recorremos la lista a partir del segundo elemento, comparandolo siempre con el elemento anterior. Si encontramos un elemento fuera de orden, cambiamos el valor a retornar y salimos del ciclo.

```
def lista_es_ordenada(lista):
    """ Verifica si la lista está ordenada.

        @param lista. Una lista de valores númericos
        @return True si la lista está ordenada.
    """
    ordenada = True
    for i in range(1, len(lista)):
        if lista[i] < lista[i - 1]:
            ordenada = False
            break
    return ordenada
```

Nota: Se define que una lista vacia es ordenada.

Construimos también unos casos de prueba para asegurarnos de que funcione:

```
print(lista_es_ordenada([]))
print(lista_es_ordenada([1]))
print(lista_es_ordenada([1, 2]))
print(lista_es_ordenada([2, 1]))
```

lo que produce:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Con esa función ya hecha y probada, la puedes usar en tu programa:

```
n=3
array = []
for i in range(n):
   x=int(input("Valores: "))
   array.append(x)

if not lista_es_ordenada(array):
    print("Lista no está ordenada")
```

**Edit**

El método propuesto es de orden `O(n)`, es decir, el tiempo que demora en chequear la lista es proporcional a n, el número de elementos en la lista. En el peor caso (cuando la lista está ordenada), tiene que recorrer la lista completa, lo que toma n pasos.

Los métodos basados en `sort` son lentos e ineficientes: primero tienes que ordenar la lista, operación de orden `O(n log n)` en el mejor de los casos, más lo que te demoras en comparar las listas, operación de `O(n)`. Además, consumen el doble de memoria (la lista + la copia ordenada).

Con casos sencillos la diferencia no es perceptible, pero cuando se trata de la vida real (lista con miles de objetos), la diferencia es inaceptable.

Es conveniente que aprendas los algoritmos básicos primero. No siempre habrá una librería que te saque del problema.

Comment: Muy interesante tu planteamiento, gracias por la explicación.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograrlo de forma sencilla, ordenando el array original y despues comparandolo ambos en original y el ordenado, si son iguales estara ordenado de lo contrario tu lista no esta ordenada.

```py
n=3
array = []
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input('valores: '))
array.append(x)
ordered_array = array.sort()
print(ordered_array)
print(array)
if array==ordered_array:
    print("Ordenado")
else:
    print("Sin ordenar")
```

Puedes adaptarlo a lo que tu quieras.